# How to make a cube in pyglet

Tags: python-3.x, pyglet

I am trying to learn pyglet, and from what I understand it is just a wrapper for openGL with some extra doodads and bits. I am real confused by how to make a cube, I have looked into tutorials on how to do so in pure openGL and, failed to translate them into pyglet. Any help would be appreciated, especially if someone could explain to me why changing things on the z-axis out of the range (1, 0, -1) makes it stop rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this [Code](https://github.com/jjstrydom/pyglet_examples/blob/master/minecraft_block.py)
You can find following code

```
def add_block(self,x,y,z):

    X, Y, Z = x+1, y+1, z+1

    tex_coords = ('t2f', (0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1))

    self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.side,   ('v3f', (X, y, z,  x, y, z,  x, Y, z,  X, Y, z)), tex_coords) # back
    self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.side,   ('v3f', (x, y, Z,  X, y, Z,  X, Y, Z,  x, Y, Z)), tex_coords) # front

    self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.side,   ('v3f', (x, y, z,  x, y, Z,  x, Y, Z,  x, Y, z)), tex_coords)  # left
    self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.side,   ('v3f', (X, y, Z,  X, y, z,  X, Y, z,  X, Y, Z)), tex_coords)  # right

    self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.bottom, ('v3f', (x, y, z,  X, y, z,  X, y, Z,  x, y, Z)), tex_coords)  # bottom
    self.batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, self.top,    ('v3f', (x, Y, Z,  X, Y, Z,  X, Y, z,  x, Y, z)), tex_coords)  # top
```

Also you can find several interesting hitns in this project. It helped me when I start learn pyglet with 3D rendering.